# Properly build http get request in ruby

Tags: ruby, http-get

I want to request user information from an API using ruby so I'm following this ruby http cheat sheet:

http://augustl.com/blog/2010/ruby_net_http_cheat_sheet/

This is what I'm using so far:

```
    #!/usr/bin/ruby
    require "net/http"
    require "uri"

    uri = URI.parse("https://cirrus.app47.com/api/users/obfuscated_userID")
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    request.initialize_http_header({"X-Token" => "obfuscated-TokenString"})
    request.initialize_http_header({"Accept" => "application/json"})

    response = http.request(request)
    puts response.to_s
```

Printing the response  gives me `#<Net::HTTPBadRequest:0x007fe37cac2da0>` so what am I doing wrong to build or execute the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things are missing:

1. Declaration that ssl is being used
2. Proper header specification

Here is the solution:

```
uri = URI.parse("https://cirrus.app47.com/api/users/obfuscated_userID") 
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port) 
http.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri) 
request['X-Token'] = "obfuscated-APIToken" 
request['Accept'] = "application/json"

response = http.request(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to call `response.body`

You can find the documentation for Net::HTTPResponse [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPResponse.html)

Comment: calling puts response.body.to_s just elaborates on the bad request error `<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.8.0</center>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0):

Try making the request using `http` protocol instead of `https`:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://cirrus.app47.com/api/users/obfuscated_userID")
```

Then, it should work as expected.

Also, try to inspect the `response` and `response body` like this:

```
response = http.request(request)
puts response.inspect
puts response.body.inspect
```

And, grab your required data :-)

Comment: using http yields `#<Net::HTTPMovedPermanently 301 Moved Permanently readbody=true>
"<html>\r\n<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.8.0</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"`

Comment: Basically, the resource you are looking for is not there anymore. It's moved to somewhere else. That's why you are getting `400 Error` using `https` and `301 status` using `http`. You have to find the correct resource url and then it should work.

Comment: See this post for some more info: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/64650/why-does-301-redirect-work-for-http-but-not-for-https

Comment: If that is true then why is it that this curl works: `curl -v -H "X-Token: obfuscated-Token" -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET https://cirrus.app47.com/api/users/obfuscated_userID`

Comment: Then probably the issue is in setting the headers in your request.